# Android - Sending notification to specific users (Firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an Android application, where I want to send a notification to specific users when a node in my database gets created.

**Database Structure**

[image]
**Question:** Is it possible to send a notification to every user in the passengers node, when the notification node gets created?

**Possible solution:** I have looked into Firebase Cloud Functions, where it seems possible to achieve this.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref(".../routes/notifications")
```

Comment: see this tutorial http://androidbash.com/firebase-push-notification-android/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The linked tutorial is sending notifications manually, or am I missing something?

Comment: I think you might be looking for something more like the [Send FCM notifications Cloud Functions sample](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications).

Comment: I believe that this require manually sending notifications from the firebase console.

Comment: @JDoe The sample Grimthorr linked sends notifications based on a database trigger, to device tokens stored in the database. It's all quite automated once you've written the code to do so. I've also written an article myself about doing this before Cloud Functions came out: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html  All these approaches are quite similar: when something happens in the database, they send a message through FCM. If you're having a hard time implementing this, you'll have to [show what you've tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have updated my post. The top node of my database is dependent on the user, as the user has possibilities of choosing between different schools. In my JavaScript code where I make a database reference: are there a way to know what the user has picked? Because I don't know what to write in my database reference in the JavaScript code.

Comment: You will need to pass the information of what the user selected to your Cloud Functions code. You can either do that by creating a separate database node for the "user wants to send notification to passengers on route xyz" action, or you can create a HTTP function for the "send notification to passengers on route xyz" action..